# Windows 11 (22H2) and Ubuntu server (Samba) problem

Tags: ubuntu, windows, upgrade, samba, domain

In February some workers in my office got new computers with Windows 11 version 22H2. After joining them to the domain (domain controller is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS), nobody could log in on these new computers.

I found a solution - to check "Use only Kerberos DES encryption for this account" in AD Users and Computers. I turned this option on for users with new computers. Then they were able to log in, but were unable to change their passwords. I left such situation as temporary solution so they could work, but I was looking for a good solution - to resolve that issue.

I found that this problem occured, because in Windows 11 22H2 update, Microsoft has changed some encryption method to avoid Year 2038 problem, but as a result Windows 11 22H2 became incompatible with samba Ubuntu server.

After many research I found that probably the only solution is to update Samba to 4.16. I did it 3 days ago, just by running `sudo apt-get update`,  `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo reboot`. Later I checked if I still have access to shared server folders on my Windows 10 computer and I had. But after running samba --version on server, I see Version 4.7.6... I don't know why. (In ADUC, I see the operating system of domain controller as Samba 4.10.16 (as before)).

Now all workers in the office don't have access to shared folders (me too) except those 3 people who has Windows 11 22H2 and DES Kerberos turned on. What's more, when I start AD Users and Computers I'm getting an error: **Naming information cannot be located because: System cannot contact domain controller to resolve auhtentication request. Try again later. Contact your system administrator to verify that your domain is properly configured and is currently online.** When I click OK, then change domain controller and type server's IP address, I can see all domain data, but when I try to change any user setting, I'm getting errors **Domain does not exist or cannot be contacted.** and **Cannot display domain name for the user for system older than Windows 2000.** When I click OK, I can see all user settings - I can change them, then after reopening the program, I still see changes, but I'm not sure if they work (e.g. I tried creating new user and then logging in as it - not working.)

I can access the server via Putty.

Please help! What should I do? Is there any solution? Did the samba update went wrong?

*****!!!UPDATE!!!*****

I resolved the above issue - I don't know how... Suddenly, it just started working.
But the main problem - Windows 11 22H2 incompatibility with Samba still persists.

My ADUC still shows domain controller operating system as Samba 4.10.16 and `samba --version` on ubuntu server returns "Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu". I don't know why there's the difference and what's more important:

**Why there is no Samba 4.16 version and how to upgrade it to 4.16 version?**

Answer (score 0):

> Bug Description
> An updated Windows 11 22H2 system fails to obtain kerberos tickets from an affected Samba AD DC server. This impacts joining such windows machines to a Samba Active Directory server, or even continued usage of already joined windows 11 22H2 machines.
> Note that the fix is in the Heimdal Kerberos code, which is embedded inside Samba.
> [ Test Plan ]
> The test involves joining an up-to-date Windows 11 22H2 system to a Samba AD DC installation on the affected Ubuntu release being tested. And similarly, join a different windows system (for example, windows 10) to the same samba domain, to ensure it keeps working unaffected by the fix.
> For all instances of this test, you need a samba AD DC. Install a samba AD DC
> server on the Ubuntu release under test, in a VM or bare metal (not lxc/lxd)

Check the full description here:

[Windows 11 22H2 and Samba-AD login issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1993934)

Become root:

```
apt update
apt install -y samba winbind smbclient
systemctl stop smbd nmbd winbind
systemctl disable smbd nmbd winbind
systemctl mask smbd nmbd winbind
systemctl unmask samba-ad-dc
systemctl enable samba-ad-dc
mv /etc/samba/smb.conf{,orig}

samba-tool domain provision \
--domain=EXAMPLE --realm=EXAMPLE.SAMBA --adminpass=Passw0rd \
--server-role=dc --use-rfc2307 --dns-backend=SAMBA_INTERNAL

dns=$(resolvectl status | grep -E "^[[:blank:]]*Current DNS Server:" | awk '{print $4}')

[ -n "$dns" ] && \
sed -r -i "s,dns forwarder = .*,dns forwarder = ${dns}," \
/etc/samba/smb.conf

unlink /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "search example.samba" >> /etc/resolv.conf
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
systemctl disable systemd-resolved
mv /var/lib/samba/private/krb5.conf /etc/
systemctl start samba-ad-dc

# relax the password settings to make it easier to test
samba-tool domain passwordsettings set --min-pwd-age=0 --complexity=off

# Create a samba user in the domain:
samba-tool user create ubuntu

# install krb5-user, to test with kinit. There should be no debconf prompts, since we have an /etc/krb5.conf already populated

apt install krb5-user -y
```

Comment: The issue is a little bit more complicated... I found that another samba instance is installed under /usr/local. When I run just `samba --version`, I'm getting "Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu" and when I run `/usr/local/samba/sbin/samba --version` I'm getting "Version 4.10.16". So the ADUC uses that samba in /usr/local/. So the solution with /etc/samba won't work... I need to update samba inside /usr/local. Now as I understand this, I started a new thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740464/how-to-update-samba-to-4-16-in-usr-local-samba (but I don't know how samba was installed there :( )

Comment: @JanCDWP that would have been really useful information to add to your question