# How to update Samba to 4.16 (in /usr/local/samba)?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, samba

I use Samba domain controller on my Ubuntu (18.04.6 LTS) server. Samba is installed in /usr/local/samba folder. Samba version is 4.10.16 and I want to update it to 4.16 (due to Windows 11 22H2 problem).

How to update Samba in /usr/local folder?

(And another question - if I update it to 4.16, will computers with Windows 10 or 11 before 22H2 be able to work with the server as before?)

Comment: So, since `/usr/local` is **not** the location that Ubuntu installs software into, you must have manually installed samba through other means. We don't know how you did that! You must figure that out, uninstall it in a compatible way, and then install the new version. Sorry, we can't help you with knowing how you installed it in the first place.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It was already installed by previous IT worker in my office. I don't know how he did it.

Comment: This seems to be a rephrased version of the original question [Windows 11 (22H2) and Ubuntu server (Samba) problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/739677/100397)